# How to get Size of file in FileInfo?

Tags: c#

I want to get the size to show in the ListView.
But my code return 0. I find.Length() get length size but only have Count() and it can't resolve my problem.

My code like:

```
string[] filePaths = (string[])e.Data.GetData(DataFormats.FileDrop, false);
List<FileInfo> fileInfos = new List<FileInfo>();  
foreach (string filePath in filePaths)
{
    FileInfo f = new FileInfo(filePath);
    fileInfos.Add(f);
    long s1 = fileInfos.Count;
    string chkExt = Path.GetExtension(f.ToString());
    s1 = s1/1024;
    decimal d = default(decimal);
    d = decimal.Round(s1, 2, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero);
    // d is 0. Because s1 = 1 only count not length of file.
```

Comment: Use length. Also integer division; make 1024.0

Comment: `FileInfo` has the property `Length`. It returns the number of bytes of the file.

Comment: `fileInfos.Count` gives the number of file infos you have read. So for eveery file up to the 1024th file, it will return 0. After that 1, etc. You've used the wrong number there. You should look for a length or size property in `f`, which is the actual file info of the current file. And maybe improve the naming so you reduce the risk of making such an error again.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are using `fileInfos`, which is a `List<T>`. You want to check the length of your actual FileInfo `f`:

```
long s1 = f.Length;
```

While you are dividing by 1024, please note, that there is a difference in units when dealing with filezises, depending on your base: 2 or 10. KB is 2^x and kB is 10^x bytes.

Answer (score 3):

The `long s1 = fileInfos.Count;` doesn't check the file length. It checks the number of members of the `fileInfos` `List`. If you want to get individual file length of the files in your `List`. Do this:

```
int index = 0; //zero is an example
long fileLength = fileInfos[index].Length;
```

or in your loop

```
long fileLength = f.Length;
```

Also, beware of your operation:

```
s1 = s1/1024;
```

Since `s1` is a `long`, you will lose some precision here... maybe you can consider to use `decimal` for `s1` from the beginning

Answer (score 1):

you can get the file size in bytes using [`Length`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.fileinfo.length(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
FileInfo f = new FileInfo(filePath);
long fileSize = f.Length;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
FileInfo fileInfo = new FileInfo(path); 
long fileLength = fileInfo.Length;
```

would give the size of the file. It is better to check whether the file exists or not before getting the size to avoid FileNotFound exception.